# Read tenantId for the loggedi in user in Angular & Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on the multitenat application using Angular and Firebase in combination with Google Cloud Identity Platform. The later one is part of the Firebase auth and allows me to group users under different tenants plus it adds the "tenantId" property to a user.
All my users and a sub-collection of a tenant document.

*The challenge I have is how to obtain a currently logged in user via Firebase auth API in time to make the query to list all the users for a given tenant.*

Imagine logged in user pasts in the browser's address bar URL http://tenant.domain.com/users. In order to retrieve this data I need to know the "tenantId" which has to come via currently logged in user which resolves later than I make my query.

I retrieve current user using the following code:

```
getCurrentUser() {
        return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
            var user = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
                if (user) {
                    resolve(user);
                } else {
                    reject('No user logged in');
                }
            })
        });
    }
```

Basically I'm looking for away to have "tenantId" available at any time and place in the application.